# How to update multiple rows with same id in a single PUT method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, postman

I have 2 tables, one is Order and other is Order details, In Order table Id is primary key and in Order Details "OrderId" is foreign key, now against OrderId "5", i have 3 rows in Order Details and i want to update these 3 rows in a single PUT method.
How can I do it ???

what to write to update multiple rows ??

// PUT api//5

```
public void Put(int id, [FromBody] string value)
{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are passing the orderDetails to be updated through an `OrderDetailsDTO`

```
public void Put(int id, [FromBody] OrderDetailsDTO orderDetails){
    foreach(var ord in orderDetails) 
    {
        var _ordDetails = _context.OrderDetails.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == ord.Id);
        _ordDetails.Amount = ord.Amount;
        _context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

This is not the most efficient way to do it but you can always modify now you have the idea.

Comment: but it will set three amounts to 75 ... i want to set three different amounts with order id 5.

Comment: in your update code it will
id    amount     suit 
5      75             pent
5       75             shirt
5       75             kurta

Comment: in your update code it will
| id | amount | suit |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
| 5  | 75    | pent |
| 5  | 75    | shirt |
| 5  | 75    | kurta |

Comment: i want this
| id | amount | suit |
|:---- |:------:| -----:|
| 5  | 75    | pent |
| 5  | 76    | shirt |
| 5  | 77    | kurta |

Comment: Please edit this clarification to your question while I update the answer